# randomly select two observation and calculate the distance

Tags: sas

I have a data set `have` with numerical column `x`. I want to randomly select any two distinct points and then calculate the distance between them.

If I only do it once, then I just use `proc surveyselect` to generate another data set with two obs.

```
proc surveyselect data=have out=want method=srs
sampsize=2;
run;

data out;
set have end=eof;
dist = abs(dif1(x));
if eof;
run;
```

But how can I do it multiple times, say 1000000? Each time two points are selected with equal prob, then finally I have 1000000 dist records.

Comment: Currently I do it using %do loop inside a macro. But that's way too slow;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about you reorder your input dataset into a random order and then calculate the distance for every second observation?

```
proc sql ;
create table random as 
    select *, ranuni(0) as randorder
    from have
    order by randorder
;quit ;

data want ;
  set random;
  dist=abs(dif1(x)) ;
  if _n_/2=int(_n_/2) ;
run;
```

If you need to specify a specific number of samples to calculate then you can add update `set random` to `set random(obs=100000)` for example. Although note this would be 'sample pairs' so 100,000 would give your `want` dataset 50,000 observations